# Unity implementation of the cachedrepository pattern

Tags: unity-container, repository-pattern, structuremap

I am trying to implement the pattern as described here http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/building-a-cachedrepository-via-strategy-pattern/ but using unity (the example uses StructureMap)

I am trying to replicate this code in Unity syntax

```
x.For<IOrganization>().Use<OrganizationCacheRepository>().Ctor<IOrganization>).Is<OrganizationRepository>();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do something like:

```
_container.RegisterType<IOrganization,OrganizationCacheRepository>(new Injection Constructor(new []{new ResolvedParameter<OrganizationRepository>()});
```

Where RegisterType registers the initial interface/type mapping and IjectionConstructor maps the paramters to be injected into the object when it is created.

We use a ResolvedParameter to tell Unity to resolve an instance from a type/interface from the container and use it as an injection parameter.

Comment: Thanks, we are dropped unity in the end :( but cos you are the only one to answer i will award ya the answer.